# Meaning of 有輪有得

Tags: meaning

A gentleman I saw today had the tattoo

> 有輪有得

I am struggling to understand if this is a legitimate sentence and what it could mean. I am familiar with 有得， expressing beneficiality. For instance:

> 學習有得

In my limited experience, 有輪 is not used to characterise people, but wheeled objects. So, my interpretation would be:

> Having wheels pays off!

Is my interpretation correct and is the sentence natural?

Comment: Does the gentleman have a lot of cars, or is into cars?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Is my interpretation correct and is the sentence natural?*

This phrase make no sense. As you said, 有輪 means ( have wheels), 有得 on the other hand, means "can" http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/18059/

There have to be some wrong characters in the phrase.

My guess is " 有輪有得" could be :"有能有德" (competent and virtuous) opposite of " 無德無能" (lack virtue and ability)

EDIT:

other possibilities:

It is a mix up of two similar phrases:

**有輸**有贏 (some lose some win)

- It can be written as 有贏有輸 (some win some lose)
- 輪 was mistaken for 輸
- It is a Cantonese phrase

**有得**有失 (some gain some lose )

- 輸: defeat ; lost (in match or gamble)
- 失: lose (something)

Answer (score 4):

Would it be possible the word is 有輸有得?

It mean that there is lost and gain.

輸(lose) and 輪(wheel) look similar anyway.

But it make more sense if the word is 輸

Comment: Very probable. I just got a glimpse! I will ask for a closer look at his tattoo- embarrassed as I may be...